# Dolphin KDE | Sidebar config-file location for backup and export

Tags: debian, kde-plasma

Where can i find the config files of the **sidebar from dolphin** (file manager), where my Bookmarks for folders and devices are saved.

I want to edit them manually, backup them and export the file to a second user profile on my debian gnu/linux.

I found only the ~/.config/dolphinrc for some global settings but not my bookmarks.

The ~/.local/share/kxmlgui5/dolphin is empty and in ~/.local/share/dolphin/view_properties i found nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

~/.local/share/user-places.xbel

Answer (score 6):

For my KDE-Dolphin GNU/LINUX Debian 10

These are the files, for my backup and export now:

**KDE-Dolphin main configuration:**

`~/.config/dolphinrc`

`~/.local/share/kxmlgui5/dolphin`

`~/.local/share/dolphin/view_properties`

`~/.local/share/kxmlgui5/dolphin/dolphinui.rc.`

**KDE-Dolphin sidebar and bookmark configuration:**

`~/.local/share/user-places.xbel`

**KDE-Dolphin keyboard shortcuts configuration:**

`~/.config/kdeglobals`

`~/.config/kglobalshortcutsrc`

`~/.config/khotkeysrc`